# Finding the solutions of $y''+y'-6y=0$

Tags: ordinary-differential-equations

Hi guys just a quick question I am not used to that I need help with.

How do I find the solutions of the following differential equations satisfying the given conditions:
$$ {\sf a})\quad y''+y'-6y = 0, \qquad y=3, y'=1\ \mathsf{when}\ x=0.$$

I'm just a bit confused because I'm used to finding the general solution not the solutions.

Comment: What is the general solution?

Comment: I get it now thanks

Answer (score 3, accepted):

So the [Characteristic equation](http://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Characteristic_equation_%28calculus%29) will be $D^2+D-6=0\implies D=-3,2$

So, $y=Ae^{-3x}+Be^{2x}$ where $A,B$ are arbitrary constants.

So, $y'=A(-3)e^{-3x}+B\cdot2e^{2x}$

Now, put the initial condition to find $A,B$

$3=y_{(x=0)}=A+B$

and $1=y'_{(x=0)}=(-3Ae^{-3x}+2B\cdot e^{2x})_{(x=0)}=-3A+2B$

Can you take up from here?

Answer (score 2):

First find the general solution:
$$y(x) = k_1e^{2x} + k_2e^{-3x}$$
When $x=0$:
$$y(0) = k_1+k_2=3$$
$$y'(0) = 2k_1-3k_2=1$$
Solving, you get that $k_1 = 2, k_2 = 1$.

Answer (score 2):

You say that you're used to finding the general solutions, so you should be aware that $$y=Ae^{2x}+Be^{-3x}\tag{1}$$ is your general solution. Then $$y'=2Ae^{2x}-3Be^{-3x}.\tag{2}$$ Given your initial conditions for the *particular* solution, then, we need $$3=A+B\quad\text{and}\quad1=2A-3B,$$ which we found simply by "plugging in" the initial values in $(1)$ and $(2)$. Solve this system for $A$ and $B,$ then "plug in" to $(1)$ to get the particular solution.